# Copy tumblr theme with all parameters

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

I have tumblr blog with Elise theme.

It has tons of configurable parameters.

Now I'd like to create one more Tumblr blog with exactly the same parameters.

Is it possible to export / import theme settings in Tumblr? Or can I just copy the blog with all theme parameters?

P.s. coping theme html doesn't work, as it copies theme only without theme parameters.

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, this isn't possible. User settings are stored server side by Tumblr.

Comment: You can export them (by simply creating a theme with all your options to be shown in the html) but you can't import them automatically—unless you interact with the options panel via javascript in the developer tools. You'd basically have to build the importer yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those settings aren't exportable in any official way.

However, if you just want to create a second Tumblr with the same text color, font, etc., you can copy the original's dynamically generated CSS (which starts under the "THEME STYLE FROM OPTIONS" comment), create a clone with the Elise theme, and replace the clone's theme style with that in the same location. The configurable parameters won't work anymore, but the styles will be identical.